# Reading BigQuery Numeric Data Type From Table

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

While reading data from BQ table [NUMERIC](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#numeric-type) data type is *Still not supported* in Apache Beam but using API I can use NUMERIC data type in BQ.

So while reading data from BQ with below Snippet:

```
BigQueryIO.readTablerow().from(options.valueprovider);
```

I got an Exception Numeric is *Not supported yet*.

Is there any other way I can read data from BQ if NUMERIC field is Present Except RestAPI Call.

Comment: I don't think it is possible right now. You can [follow the relevant feature request for Beam](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-4417), however.

Comment: Hi, @ElliottBrossard That request i have seen but there is no response on from Apache side till now. Any alternative So, I can test the behaviour of Numeric Datatype in Dataflow Instead of RestAPI Call. I trying to use user-defined Coder also if it may help or any alternatives/Suggestions.

Comment: https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/5755

Comment: @ElliottBrossard Thanks

Comment: @ElliottBrossard I have Tried to run Dataflow Using the master branch build of 2.6.0-SNAPSHOT Numeric DataType is merged in Master but getting Error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: com.google.common.base.VerifyException: Expected Avro schema type STRING, not BYTES, for BigQuery NUMERIC field

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I'll look into fixing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dataflow now supports [reading `NUMERIC` from BigQuery](https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/5948) using the Java library. At the time of this writing, you will either need to [download a snapshot release](https://builds.apache.org/view/A-D/view/Beam/job/beam_PostRelease_NightlySnapshot/295/) or wait until the next [official Beam release](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/downloads/#releases) in order to make use of this feature.

Edit: if you want to download the current version of Beam, you can do so like this:

```
~$ git clone https://github.com/apache/beam.git
```

Then you can use the Gradle `build` task, for example:

```
~$ cd beam
~/beam$ ./gradlew build
```

Or generate files for Eclipse, if you're using it as your development environment:

```
~/beam$ ./gradlew -p sdks/java/build-tools/ eclipse
```

You can find more information about using Gradle [in the Gradle user documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide.html).

Comment: Thanks for Information But can you please share the command to build gradle Since i am Facing Issue and Now maven build is not possible with master branch due to the absence of pom.xml.

Comment: I updated the answer to show a couple of Gradle tasks that you can execute.